# Using String Format for Two Parameters in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem in using String Format for two parameters in C#. Here I want to show data that bigger than and lower than value I inputted. For data which is not included in that criteria, I want to show in another DataGridView. Anyone can help me ? Here my code :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(koneksinectar);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", kon);
DataSet coba = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(coba);

var table = coba.Tables[0];
var view = new DataView(table);
var view2 = new DataView(table);

if (textBox1.Text != "")
{
  sb.Append(string.Format("[Saldo] > '{0}'", textBox1.Text));
}

if (textBox2.Text != "")
{
  if (sb.Length > 0)
  {
    sb.Append(" AND ");
  }

  sb.Append(string.Format("[Saldo] < '{0}'", textBox2.Text));
}

sb2.Append(string.Format(//here I want to do the formula textBox1.Text < [Saldo] > textBox2.Text)); //What code I must write ?

view.RowFilter = sb.ToString();
view2.RowFilter = sb2.ToString();

ViewNectarGV.DataSource = view;
NectarUnscheduleGV.DataSource = view2;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C#6 you can simply do

```
$"'{textBox1.Text}' < [Saldo] AND [Saldo] > '{textBox2.Text}'";
```

otherwise you can do

```
string.Format("'{0}' < [Saldo] AND [Saldo] > '{1}'",textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
```

Comment: I have tried your code and error says Cannot perform '>' operation on System.Boolean and System.String.

Comment: That should now work. Before your query was doing the first less than, this will output a bool. You are then doing a greater than on a bool and the second value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but I think this is what you want.
Assuming the textboxes should be int's and you are trying to find if they are larger than or less than.

```
int num1;
int num2;
if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "") {
    num1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    num2 = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
   string str;
   if(num1 > num2) {
       str = string.Format("{0} > {1}", num1, num2);
   } else if(num1 < num2) {
       str = string.Format("{0} < {1}", num1, num2);
   } else {
       str = string.Format("{0} = {1}", num1, num2);
   }
}
```